# Convert array to string with double quotes in php

Tags: php

I have following array

```
$type=Array(
[0] => PL
[1] => LWP
[2] => Carry Forward
[3] => SL
);
```

I want to convert it into String.I used implode function to convert it.

```
$newarray=implode(",", $type);
```

but it reurn string like below

```
PL,LWP,Carry Forward,SL
```

I want String like below

```
("PL","LWP","Carry Forward","SL")
```

Please help me...

Comment: well, for starters, you want quotes inbetween your values instead of just commas - have you tried using a glue for implode *that has quotes*?

Comment: `$newString = "(" . implode("\",\"", $type) . ")";`

Answer (score 6):

Try this one ;)

```
$newarray='("'.implode('","', $type).'")';
```

Answer (score 2):

As you want double quotes in the string generated,you can replace the glue of implode with `implode('", "', $type)` instead of `implode(", ", $type)`
These double quotes will not appear in the 1st and last value of string.. So add `("` in the beginning and `")` at the end of implode.
See the code below for entire syntax

```
<?php
    $type=Array(
    [0] => PL
    [1] => LWP
    [2] => Carry Forward
    [3] => SL
    );
    //Convert array to string with double quotes for each value
    $newarray='("'.implode('", "', $type).'")';
    echo $newarray;
    ?>
```

Comment: @TobySpeight Edited..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `","` glue and adding prefix `("` and postfix `")`

```
$newarray= '("' . implode('","', $type) . '")';
```

You should also think about edge case when you have empty array since you may want to handle it slightly different. In this case it would result `("")`

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, your question is unanswerable. You are trying to create a machine parseable representation of data without providing nearly enough information about how this is to be parsed.

e.g. What if one the elements already contains a double quote - you need to escape it. But which method do you use for escaping?

e.g. Quoting a numerical value may then affect its interpretation by the consumer of the data (although your example does not include numerical data).

You might consider using [fputcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php); (but this will only write to a [stream](http://php.net/manual/en/book.stream.php) - so if you need the data elsewhere then you'd need to capture the stream.

Answer (score 0):

The current answers disregard the edge case of `$type` being empty by returning `("")` instead of `()` which is probably what you want.

You may want to surround each element by quotes before adding the parentheses like so:

```
$type = array("PL", "LWP", "Carry Forward", "SL");
$quoted = array_map( function($element) { return "\"${element}\""; }, $type );
$newarray = '(' . implode(',', $quoted) . ')';
```